# How to insert in c# using custom table name

Tags: c#, sql-server

This is partial code which i try

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=ANSARI-PC\;Initial Catalog=BMS;Integrated Security=True");
    string tname = idc + "-InvoiceT";
    string sql = "select count(*) from '"+ tname + "' ";
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand sda = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
    SqlDataReader myreader;
    myreader = sda.ExecuteReader();
    int lid;
```

For above code im getting this error Incorrect syntax near '2-InvoiceT'
2-InvoiceT is table name in database 'idc' contain 2 as value.

Comment: Putting quotes around the table name transforms that name in a string and, of course, this is a syntax error. So remove the quotes. But I would also advise you to not allow your user to type the table name. Allow only a whitelist of names that your user should choose from a readonly control like a ListBox or DropDownList

Comment: Personally, I would use a parametrised dynamic statement. What are you have ther is dangerously open to injection. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=9ef5e3230cc65cf5042769920a633753)

Comment: Seems Syntax error and not mentioned table name properly.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Change

```
string sql = "select count(*) from '"+ tname + "' ";
```

to

```
string sql = "select count(*) from ["+ tname + "] ";
```

Comment: This far from solves the injection issue, which is a major flaw here.

Comment: That is correct, you should never allow your users to type the table name like that, but that wasn't the question.

Comment: Just because it's not the question doesn't mean that a bad answer is the correct answer. An answer that has a huge security flaw is not a good answer, and that flaw needs to be address.

Comment: @Z3esha9 I strongly suggest you **do not** use this answer as it stands.

Comment: Glad I could help. And yes, you should be careful with the injection thing.

Comment: You can lead a horse to water, I suppose... I hope you address the security flaw here @Z3esha9 ; otherwise you may well learn about it the hard way.

Comment: Actually user is not inserting the table, its define by record id of other table "compant" followed by invoicet.